# Matplotlib: Shared titles between rows within subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose we have the following:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(0, 3):
  # Left plot
  ax[i,0].plot(data1[i].x, data1[i].y)
  # Right plot
  ax[i,1].plot(data2[i].x, data2[i].y)
```

Such that there are three rows and two columns with six figures in total. Is it possible to add a shared title for each row of the subplot? I can't think of anything better than adding a title for each axes (e.g. `ax[i,0].set_title('Left part of figure')`).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `fig.text()` to add text to one of the axes on each row and then shift the text to the center of the row. For example, the following adds text to the right axes in each row and positions it to the left so that it's centered on the row:

```py
ax[i,0].set_title(' ') # make a blank space for the title
fig.text(-0.05, 1.15, '- Some title -', horizontalalignment='center',
  verticalalignment='center', transform=ax[i,1].transAxes)
```

Adding a blank title helps set the vertical space between rows to the right amount, as otherwise the space is too small.